# Use eval() with different local scope

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how it is possible to call eval() with data from a different local scope.

Something like:

```
function doSomething() {
    var y = 1;
    print_and_eval('y+1');
}

function print_and_eval(data) {
    print(data);
    eval(data);
}
```

**Edit:**
- It is safe to use eval() in my case. Please do not recommend this as a solution.
- The main problem is, that I have local variables in doSomething() which are not defined in print_and_eval(). The evaluation then leads to an 'ReferenceError: y is not defined' error.

```
js> print_and_eval('var a = {x:1}')
var a = {x:1}
js> print_and_eval('print(a.x)')    
print(a.x)
typein:3012: TypeError: a is null
```

I would like to receive the output '1' in this case.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no easy way to do this in Javascript. However, another, more specific term for what you call "local scope" is often referred to as "binding scope" or "binding context", referring to the values the variables bind to.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? I'm sure the problem can be solved just passing a function around (with context)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the other comment of "don't use eval".

That being said, another alternative to it being global would be to pass it to the other function:

```
function doSomething() {
    var y = 1;
    print_and_eval('y+1', y);
}

function print_and_eval(data, y) {
    print(data);
    eval(data);
}
```

This would obviously require you to know the variable name before-hand.